# Memory leak in my implementation of command pattern - C#

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, ram

I have a small issue with memory leak...
I have tried to implement some variation of command design pattern but I can't find the spot where RAM is leaking.
I used thread with infinite loop where I check the quantity of elements in synchronized queue.
(I know that this is not the best solution but as a simple example it seemed fine for me - at least at the beginning).
This is my code for thread and queue:

```
    public class WorkerThread
    {
        public Queue commandQueue = Queue.Synchronized(new Queue());
        private Thread th;

        public WorkerThread()
        {
            th = new Thread(RunThread);
            Command.SetParentThread(this);
            th.Start();
        }

        public void RunThread()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                while(commandQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (commandQueue.Peek() is Command)
                    {
                        ((Command)commandQueue.Dequeue()).DoAction();
                    }
                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }

        public void AddTaskToQueue(Command cmd)
        {
            commandQueue.Enqueue(cmd);
            cmd = null;
        }
    }
```

Then I have created abstract command class with one abstract method (DoAction) and static method to get reference to the working thread:

```
    public abstract class Command
    {
        private static WorkerThread wk;

        public static void SetWK(WorkerThread wk)
        {
            Command.wk = wk;
        }

        public abstract void DoAction();
    }
```

Finally I have implemented Command in some real class - CommandTask:

```
    public class CommandTask : Command
    {
        public System.IO.StreamWriter sw;

        public Bitmap bitmap;

        public string dateAndTime;

        public override void DoAction()
        {
            sw.WriteLine(dateAndTime);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Dispose();
            bitmap.Dispose();
            dateAndTime = null;

        }
    }
```

When I want to create some simple command and add it to the queue I use then code like this:

```
            CommandTask ct = new CommandTask();
            ct.sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("file.txt", false);
            ct.dateAndTime = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            ct.bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(500, 500, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format64bppArgb);
            wk.AddTaskToQueue(ct);
```

Within DoAction I dispose both StreamWriter handle and bitmap but still I experience RAM leakages.
This has caused me a lot of trouble, what am I doing wrong? Is there something I am not seeing correctly (or at all)?

Comment: When you say you're experiencing RAM leakages, what does that mean exactly?

Comment: How are you measuring your _leak_?  A garbage collected run-time can often look like it has memory leaks.  Generally, Dispose does not result in used memory being returned immediately

Comment: I had this (slightly more complex version) run on my PC for a two days and when program tried to allocate memory for larger image there has been an error in the code due to insufficient memory. I have then stripped my program to this exact code and after 3h I have seen that there is used about 10% of my total RAM by this single program.

Comment: maybe let GC run once a while? also, is it possible DoAction() will be skipped because of some exception?

Comment: @urlreader - That may be a good point. Should I try GC.Collect() or something else will be more suited? Normally in my larger program I have try-catch-finally so I don't believe there is possibility to skip  DoAction().

Comment: why not do try-catch-finally in DoAction()?

Comment: Can you please post a [mre] somewhere?

Comment: @urlreader - There is also try-catch-finally in every DoAction() at the larger version of the program. Here, for test purposes, I have stripped the code to bare minimum.

Comment: maybe you did not dispose something draw on the bitmap? like font, ...

Comment: Where are you disposing ct?  Class object are passed ByRef in c# where each reference is an external link.  The class object has an external link count which is number of times object is referenced.  The dispose method will not remove an object unless the external link count is zero.  Try setting bitmap = null before disposing.  c# is managed and to prevent exception from occurring you do not want to remove an object if it is still referenced by an object.

Comment: Your code does not build (tried in VS2019, .Net 4.5 / 6). Where are you putting the last patch - creating command task, stream writer and calling AddTaskToQueue function? @GuruStron is correct. Please post a minimal reproducible example.